# How to auto select a drop-down option using angular

Tags: angularjs

What is the best way to auto -select a dropdown option using angular? for example ..

```
//controller
$scope.data = [{id: 1, status: "sent"}, {id: 2, status : "Not Sent"}]

//view.. How do i set it here to always have the status on "Not sent" to be already selected when the page is loaded? 
 <div> 

     <select> 
               ng-options="status.status as status.status for status in data">

   </select>

</div>
```

Thank you for your time! AL

Comment: `<select ng-model="thatOption"> `?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
// controller
$scope.data = [{id: 1, status: "sent"}, {id: 2, status : "Not Sent"}];
$scope.selectedOption = $scope.data[0];

// view
<select ng-model='selectedOption' ng-options='d as d.status for d in data'>
```

Answer (score 2):

You just have set `model="string"` :

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
  
  $scope.data = [{id: 1, status: "sent"}, {id: 2, status : "Not Sent"}]
  $scope.selectedData = $scope.data[1];
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
 <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl"> 
   <select ng-model="selectedData"
           ng-options="status.status for status in data">
   </select>
</div>
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select

Answer (score 1):

youd should define model for select tag.
try this.

```js
angular.module('myApp', []).controller('myTest', function($scope) {

$scope.data = [{id: 1, status: "sent"}, {id: 2, status : "Not Sent"}];
  $scope.select = $scope.data[0].status;

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app = "myApp">
  <div ng-controller="myTest">
  <div> 

     <select ng-model="select"
               ng-options="status.status as status.status for status in data">

   </select>

</div>
   </div>
</div>
```